# Execute a stored procedure with parameters in C++ using SQL Server Database

Tags: c++, sql-server

I am not able to execute a stored procedure for my C++ console application. I am completely new to the C++ world. It is not able to bind the data parameter which is required to execute the procedure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Definitions

    constexpr auto SQL_RESULT_LEN = 240;
    constexpr auto SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN = 2048;

    // Define handles and variables 

    SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlStmtHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle;
    SQLWCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];

    // Bind input parameter for the date
    SQLWCHAR dateParam[11] = L"2023-07-24"; // Change to your desired date
    SQLLEN  dateParamInd = SQL_NTS;

    // Initializations

    sqlConnHandle = NULL;
    sqlStmtHandle = NULL;

    // Allocations

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle))
    {
        goto COMPLETED;
    }

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
    {
        goto COMPLETED;
    }

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle))
    {
        goto COMPLETED;
    }

    // Outputs 

    cout << "Attempting to connect to SQL Server..." << endl;

    switch (SQLDriverConnectW(sqlConnHandle,
        NULL,
        (SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=7.7.7.7; Database=abc; UID=sa; PWD=123;",
        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))

    {
    case SQL_SUCCESS:
    {
        cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server" << endl;
        break;
    }
    case SQL_ERROR:
    {
        cout << "Could not connect to SQL Server" << endl;
        goto COMPLETED;
    }

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLBindParameter(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_DATE, 10, 0, dateParam, 0, &dateParamInd))
    {
        cout << "Error binding parameter" << endl;
        goto COMPLETED;
    }

    // Execute the stored procedure
    if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirectW(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)L"EXEC [dbo].[GenerateNAV] @DateParameter", SQL_NTS))
    {
        cout << "Error executing stored procedure" << endl;
        goto COMPLETED;
    }

    // Fetch and display the result set
    SQLCHAR columnName[SQL_RESULT_LEN];
    SQLSMALLINT numColumns;

    SQLNumResultCols(sqlStmtHandle, &numColumns);

    while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i)
        {
            SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, i, SQL_CHAR, columnName, SQL_RESULT_LEN, NULL);
            cout << columnName << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

It will print 'Error Binding Parameter'. All I want to do is Execute a stored procedure from a console application and it will return a table which I want to use later.
I am also not sure about this approach for making sql server connection. Is there a better way to do this? If yes, please tag the resource. How can I fix the above code to execute the stored procedure successfully with the dateParameter

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... where do you allocate `sqlStmtHandle`?